# Manipulating active content area of each tab in menu

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I continue my experiments with HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript. I continue making a simple interactive game for my kids. Here is jsfiddle for my template: jsfiddle.net/LmCwZ/ 
The question is how I can work with each tab and populate it with a content it separately? Because in some of them I want to insert images and text. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply extend the object with more properties to hold your content such as text, images or draw commands etc.

For example, to add text capability:

```
var Tab = function(id, x, y, width, height, text, color) {

    ...snipped

    this.content = null;

    ...snipped
```

and then after creating the tab (or extend its constructor) you define the text:

```
myTab.content = 'Text for this tab!';
```

Now in the update method you can render the text of the current tab if there is any:

```
function showContent(tab) {
    ctx.fillStyle = tab.color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, tab.height, ctx.canvas.width, 700);

    // has text?   
    if (tab.content !== null) {
        ctx.fillStyle = tab.textColor;
        ctx.textAlign = 'left';
        ctx.font = '40px sans-serif';
        ctx.fillText(tab.content, 30, 160);
    }
}
```

**[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/LmCwZ/2/)**

The text color, position could just as easily be part of the properties of the object (tab.textX, tab.textY etc.).

With this approach you do not need to worry about indexes (which is a nice alternative though) as everything is self-contained in the object.

Do the same for image but be aware that image loading is asynchronous so it is an advantage to store the image object itself on the tab object rather than an url (or use the constructor phase to pre-load the image).

Also, you will have to manually format text as this is canvas (or use SVG in combination with canvas for more complex stuff as I [show in this article](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/10/using-svg-to-automatically-format-and-wrap-text-on-a-canvas-element/)). This includes text wrapping, lines etc.

If you need advanced formatting in each tab I would recommend standard HTML and CSS instead of using canvas.

Comment: I hoped that I will find you here :) Thank you very much for your help. I will go deep, hopefully everything will be fine.

Comment: @user3340575 no problem :) And just throw us more questions if you get stuck.

Comment: I wanted to show you, what I want to have for this main page http://imgur.com/5Anzfny I want to do that in canvas, what you can recommend me to do? Because I'm very worried how I can do it especially in canvas?

Comment: @user3340575 it's *possible* to do with canvas but it's gonna involve a lot of calculations - you are basically wanting to create a layout engine. I believe it's a bit outside the scope for what SO is for but you would have to calculate all sizes, positions, relations and so forth - it can quickly become "out of hand" overview wise if you don't have a clear plan ahead. If canvas is not strictly required I would still recommend HTML/CSS which is well tested (and fast) layout engine in most browsers. You can combine it with more complex image layouts having canvas as an element of the layout.

Comment: @user3340575 (continued) If the images on the other hand are in fixed positions then you could use a canvas for only those images with preset coordinates (they would be scalable), another div element for text layout and so forth. My 2 cents..

Comment: Can you please give me your email, I want to contact you directly and buy you a coffee and ask couple of questions :)